# IOS: How to do twitter integration using Fabric for ios8 and ios9

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter-fabric

For ios9 Twitter integration using Fabric is working fine but when I am doing it for ios8 its showing all the 3 error

1) Could not build module 'TwitterKit'
2) Could not build module 'TwitterCore'
3) Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found

Comment: your problem isn't quite clear please elaborate...

Comment: For twitter integration when I am using Fabric for iOS9 or xcode7 its working fine, but when I an launching this same on IOS8 or IOS7 device its showing error.
And with xcode6 its showing all the 3 errors mentioned in the question.

Comment: have you tried changing deployment target in xcode 7 with ios to ios 8 or ios 7?....or you are using xcode 6.* for ios 8 n below?...the twittercore doesn't support iOS 7 so you have to keep iOS 8 as deployment target

Comment: i tried it on ios8 only and got the errors...
for what it is running successfully is another system installed is
But my requirement is to make it compatible with ios8 and ios9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting deployment target to iOS 8 (for project and target)in xcode 7 or above.I faced similar problem when i tried building using xcode 6.3.Also you can't iOS 7 as deployment target as **TwitterCore** doesn't support for iOS 7.Hope it helps :)

**Edit**

setting deployment target for **project** [image]

For setting deployment target for target

[image]

I have used **xcode 7.2** for running on device.It doesn't give any error.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.4 for this. Its not working for me... :(
If it is working properly in IOS9 than it will woke properly with IOS8 or not?

Comment: development target is set to 8.0 and please once make me confirm how to set target for a project?

Comment: what are you using cocoapods or fabric app?...are you sure you have used xcode 7 or above cause in above comment you have said you are using xcode 6.4...